# cannot stop container: : Cannot kill container : unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: fatal error: runtime: out of memory

Tags: mysql, linux, docker

I took the mysql backup from one Linux environment using below command,
*docker exec CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=root DATABASE > backup.sql*

Then i tried to restore the above sql dump to another Linux environment with below command,
*cat backup.sql | docker exec -i CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=root DATABASE*

Since it was taking more than 15 min, I stopped it with ctrl+c and now i am getting below error when i try to do anything with docker command. Please help.

"*cannot stop container: : Cannot kill container : unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: fatal error: runtime: out of memory*"

Comment: Try and restart the docker daemon.

Comment: After restarting the linux server itself resolved the issue..... Thanks

Comment: Now i am facing the Joomla login issue,
I have exported the Joomla DB dump from Production application and imported the same production sql dump file to my development environment. Now when i launch the development site then it logs me in only with the production credentials. This issue could be because of using Prod db dump in Development. so some configuration is there inside DB tables which is forcing me to use Prod credentials in Development site.

I know there is a table in Database where the urls and credentials are mentioned but i am not sure which table it is.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting the linux server itself resolved the issue..... Thanks